# will the workflow that get started by a Retension Policy , run for each item inside the list

Tags: 2013, development, content-type, configuration, retention

I am working on SharePoint 2013 site collection. and i want to be sending emails & update list items if the item has a status of "New" & its review date = Today.

To achive this i did the following steps:-

1. I created a reusable workflow and i assign the workflow with a content type, as follow:-

[image]

now the workflow will check the item status & review date and then will send an email and update the item status accordingly.

2. then i went to "Site Collection Setting >> Content type", and i set the following retention policy for the content type:-

[image]

Now I am not sure if this mean that the workflow I define in step number 1,  will run for each  item inside the associated list ? or i need to have a loop inside the workflow to check all the related items ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The workflow will run for each item that meets the retention policy. When the timer jobs process the information and finds an item that is to expire, it will do what ever is specified as per the policy. If is to move it to the recycle bin, it moves all matching items to the recycle bin. If it is run a workflow, it runs a workflow on each item.

This process is handled by [2 timer jobs](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc678870.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) on the server, their default setting is to run weekly. They are information management policy and expiration policy.

Information management policies are a great way to manage content.

Comment: thanks for the reply,,, but i am not sure what do you mean by ". When the timer jobs process the information and finds an item that is to expire" now in my case i do not have any expiration for the item,, i just want to call a wok flow which will send an email to the associated person if the item "Review Date" is equal today & its status = "New"??

Comment: The policy process execution is handled by 2 timer jobs on the server, updated with more info

Comment: thanks for you update,, so if i want the retention policy to run once a day, then i have to configure these 2 jobs to run daily ? will this have any performance drawbacks,, i mean since they are set to run weekly,, will setting them to run daily a bad practice ?

Comment: we have not seen any performance impact in our farm by scheduling these to run daily on our desired web application.

Comment: ok thanks again for the reply,, but i need to set the schedule in a way that the "Information management policy" job should run before the "Expiration policy",, is this correct? i mean for example to set the "Information management policy" job to run daily at 12:01 AM , while the "Expiration policy" to run daily at 1:05 AM ? or the order of these 2 jobs do not have any impact ?

Comment: Expiration has to come second, information management policy marks them for expiration, and expiration policy cleans them up. If set wrong, then things get processed a day after intended.

Comment: so now i am planning to create a reusable workflow which will be sending emails & update list items if the item has a status of "New" & its review date = Today. then I will link this workflow to the associated content type. after that i will set a Retension Policy on the content type to execute the workflow once a day.. is this valid ?

Comment: In theory, i haven't used the recurance in practice, so you'll just have to test it over the course of a couple days.

Comment: and i did not use it before , actually i did not set any retention policy before.. but recurrence is suppose to work (in theory),, but other than this will this approach work :- to create a reusable workflow which will be sending emails & update list items if the item has a status of "New" & its review date = Today. then I will link this workflow to the associated content type. after that i will set a Retension Policy on the content type to execute the workflow once a day.??